# Use existing taxonomy archive page as homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called `worktype` that acts as the main filter for our portfolio projects (a CPT). The page has a filter by worktype that opens the specific archive. These archive pages are already coded and now I'd like to use one of them as the default homepage for our site: `/worktype/all`

All the solutions I've found so far are about recreating the template in the home but with that I get two versions of the same page.
I was looking to set the existing page as the home so that when I'm on one of the other pages like `/worktype/branding` and click on the `all` tab it takes me back to the home and not to the original link `/worktype/all`.

This way I would also only need one template file for whenever changes are needed.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You could just use the home.php as people have suggested but blank except include the template include('file-name.php'); I haven't tested but your loop may not work when set to home so might need to be rewritten. Do you have just one template file for all taxonomy terms? Or do you have a specific one for all worktypes?

Comment: I have a specific template for `taxonomy-worktype.php`.
I currently have a `front-page.php` with `<?php get_template_part( 'taxonomy-worktype' ); ?>` to load the page but the problem remains as when I click on all it takes me to `/worktype/all` instead of home

Comment: Have you tried redirect from /worktype/all to home instead?

Comment: I hadn't but yes, that works. Thanks!